# FQL: query for posts in a group commented on my me()

Tags: facebook-fql

I've been looking at many permutations of this query on StackOverflow, but nothing quite like this, and I can't figure it out.

I'm after the posts, in a specific group, that have been commented on by `me()` (the current user).

I can see how to get all the posts (and comments) which is simple enough:

```
SELECT post_id, comments FROM stream WHERE source_id=GROUP_ID
```

But to then reach into the comments to further filter on the `fromid` of `me()` is alluding me.  Is this a job for a multi-query?  Or is there some kind of `IN` clause I need to run?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need a multiquery for this, if all you're getting is the post id and comments. Try this:

```
SELECT post_id, fromid, text FROM comment WHERE post_id IN
  (SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=GROUP_IDENTIFIER)
  AND fromid=me()
```

Comment: That's awesome!  Works a treat (just needed to change `from_id` to `fromid` - seems FB is inconsistent with their use of `snake_case` naming.  Thanks a ton.